# Cast function output as column name

Tags: mysql

I have come across a scenario where I need to "cast" the output of a function as the column name I want to select:

```
(SELECT
LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%b'))
FROM lang_months
WHERE langRef = lang_statements.langRef
) AS month
```

Just returns the current month which is expected, but I want this to select the column called "may" in this case.

How would I do this?

---

Thanks, your answer gave me an idea. I just put the current date into a variable and used that in the query like so:

$thisMonth = strtolower(date('M')) ;

```
(SELECT
$thisMonth
FROM lang_months
WHERE langRef = lang_statements.langRef
) AS month
```

Comment: Take a look at the pivot queries with MySQL.

Comment: Oh, I was just too late with my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  The name of an entity must be known when the query reaches MySQL.

The easiest option would probably be to determine the column name in whatever language you're using then to just use that.  For example, in PHP:

```
$col = 'someAlias';
$query = "SELECT blah as `{$col}` FROM tbl";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

You could create a view that offers this view on your data so you can they query it more expressively, but you're still going to have to write those 12 subqueries and aliases by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$month = LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%b'));       // Results in 'may'
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM $month');  // Returns all records in table 'may'
```